# comparing two rows with matching field values in different coulmns

Tags: sql, loops

I have the following fields in a table 1.

```
A B C X1 X2 X3
```

Also there is a look up table with 2 columns. Both the columns can be joined with Column A in table 1

```
A1 A2
```

I am trying to verify that all the fields are matching between A1 and A2 by joining it with Table 1.

```
A1 B C X1 X2 X3
should match 
A2 B C X1 X2 X3
```

However, the values of X1, X2 & X3 can be present in any order between these 3 columns. I need to run a loop to make sure all 3 values are matching even if they are in different order. Please let me know how can I do it

Comment: You actually should rather change the table design. Can you do that?

Comment: I'm not getting this. Can you post the query as it would look like if the values `X1`, `X2` and `X3` had a fixed order?